# Remove pair duplicates from two columns in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

Let `DT` be a `4 x 2` data table with two columns, `X` and `Y`, and the following values:

```
X|Y
---
1 2
2 1
3 4
4 3
```

I want to remove duplicated pairs from the data table, namely row 2 and 4 in `DT`.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
df[!duplicated(paste0(pmax(X, Y), pmin(X, Y))), ]

   X Y
1: 1 2
2: 3 4
```

The same with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID = paste0(pmax(X, Y), pmin(X, Y))) %>%
 slice(1)
```

Or with `base R`:

```
df[!duplicated(with(df, paste0(pmax(X, Y), pmin(X, Y)))), ]
```